# Using OpenID with server-side JavaScript (node.js), but I get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, openid, serverside-javascript

Using the code from [this](https://github.com/havard/node-openid/blob/master/sample.js) example, I open the browser, type "localhost/" and I get the page with that login form. I type the URL to my blogspot, but I get the following error: error:Invalid AuthRequest: 0x300: Error verifying return URL in auth request. ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0. What am I doing wrong here?

And oh yeah, I almost forgot, how do I store data with OpenID? Appart from just logging in with that account, I'd like to save information about the user as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an error from the provider stating that it was unable to verify your return URL. Does your provider accept localhost return URLs?

To request additional information about the authenticated user, use an OpenID extension such as [Simple Registration (SREG)](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html) and/or [Attribute Exchange (AX)](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html). The sample you refer to uses both SREG and AX to request information such as nickname, e-mail, and full name, which can be retrieved from the result if the following conditions are met:

- Authentication was successful.
- The provider has the requested information about the user.
- The user agreed to share this information with you.